# merge two csv file in linux

Tags: linux, csv, text-processing

I am trying to merge two csv file into one single file in following way.
first file: contain all data.
second file: contain data updated.

so the resulted file should contain all data with row modified via second file data..

example:

```
file1:
1,Hello,123
2,Hello,456
3,Bye,789

file2:
1,Hello,123
3,Hello,789
4,Bye,345

resulted file:
1,Hello,123
2,Hello,456
3,Hello,789
4,Bye,345
```

all new entry should be added, no old entry should be removed, any updated entry should be updated in resulted.

I am looking for some simpler solution via some shell script.

Thanks in Advance. :)

Comment: Are you missing newlines?

Comment: missing newline? if needed i can add it in preprocessing the file

Comment: NM, someone edited your question. Please note what they did - that's how it should look like. Also is any language OK or just bash/csh?

Comment: ok got it. yes it should be like this

Comment: actually i already have shell script in place, so looking for some unix command or some solution via shell itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the first element in the files is the key, you can do it with `awk` like this:

*parse.awk*

```awk
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }

FNR == NR { 
  h[$1] = $0
  next
} 

{ h[$1] = $0 }

END { 
  for(k in h)
    print h[k]
}
```

Run it like this:

```
awk -f parse.awk file1 file2
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{h[$1]=$0;next} {h[$1]=$0}END{for(k in h)print h[k]}' FS=, OFS=, file1 file2
```

Output in both cases:

```
1,Hello,123
2,Hello,456
3,Hello,789
4,Bye,345
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to better define the term "data updated."

If your file 1 has this line

> 3,Bye,789

and file 2 has these lines

> 3,Hello,789
>
> 4,Bye,345

then you need to specify what is considerd "updated".  Is the first number your data key?  Is the word the key? Is the case significant?  Is the last number your key?

Then you specify

> no old entry should be removed

but your results file does not include the line

> 3,Bye,789

So clearly you expect data to be removed.

Once you have better defined your criteria, then you can begin programming a solution.

Comment: first number is my key.
old entry should be updated if the key exist in 2nd file.
for these files, result should be like this:

3,Hello,789
4,Bye,345

(3 was in both file, 2nd file data should be there in final result in this case)

Comment: This isn't an answer, You should move this to comments I think.